# UInt16 only has 256 buckets

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, histogram

I used gdal_translate to converted a Float32 DEM to a UInt16 .tif and then ran gdalinfo -hist. In the histogram it says that it has 256 buckets. I also ran -hist on a 8bit .tif and that also has 256 buckets. Does that mean that the values doesn't span over the whole spectrum in my 16bit .tif and if so what would I do to make more of the range used? 
The min and max in the histogram is 0 and 65535.

I want to get as much values as possible in my 16bit as I plan to use it as a heightmap/displacement map later and want as much of the original detail in there as possible.

This is what I ran with gdal_translate

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot UInt16 -scale -5660.574 -5618.043 0 65535 input.tif output.tif
```

Comment: Perhaps gdalinfo is coded to report histogram with 256 buckets. Number of buckets in not necessarily the same as number of possible distinct values in data. The number of buckets can be set in code, though, see http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html.

Comment: Ok, I see, I guess it would be a very long list if it would display all values of 16bit or larger. So then I should look at the histogram in another application. Thanks!

Comment: There has been some discussion about related issue http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Histograms-without-null-pixels-td5038438.html. Python script and QGIS were mentioned.

Comment: I have QGIS so I'll use that, I don't have to look at so many tif:s so that will work for me, thanks!